# Difference between indexing columns in data.table and data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

```
DF = data.frame(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

When I write `DF[2,3]`,it shows 2 because that is row 2, col 3. But as for `DT[2,3]`, it shows 3? I would like to know how this value 3 is arrived at, and if I want row 2 col 3. What should I do?

Comment: This is covered in the [very first FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

This is a common source of confusion in `data.table`.  the second `j` argument in `[.data.table` is "*evaluated within the frame of the data.table; i.e., it sees column names as if they are variables*", so the 3 that you got unexpectedly is the result of evaluating the value 3 that you passed.

you can access the 3rd column by name

```
DT[2,v]
```

or by index if you specify with=FALSE

```
DT[2,3, with=FALSE]
```

Type `?data.table` at the command line to see the help page for this